# Link between the two tables with the same values, the results will be repeated when the linkage

Tags: sql

[image]

i use these code `SELECT  id , date 
FROM table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT  id ,k1'

FROM ork9
group by id
ORDER BY k1,k3 ASC`
but the recode Duplicate

Comment: what output you are expecting?

Comment: out put like these {1 ---- 1/1/2017 )next (1------null)

Comment: you have used "union all" in your query, this will return all rows. It will not remove duplicates.. Your query is correct

Comment: Can you please describe you whole output?? and are those 2 tables or three? bcz you have mention table1 twice.

Comment: ok i want out put like table3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

union will be not good option try this

```
select table2.id,table1.date from table2 
left join table1 on table1.id = table2.id
```

This will return your expected result

Comment: no i have two table not 3 >>>>i want output like table3

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.id, t1.date FROM table1 t1 right join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

This will join the two tables and bring all records from table2 and only dates from table1